# How to use JRouter to rewrite controller and task URLs?

Tags: joomla, url-routing, joomla1.5, joomla-sef-urls, sef

I'm using Joomla 1.5 with **router.php** file to rewrite URLs of **views**. Here are contents of **router.php**:

```
<?php
function PvcCalcProBuildRoute( &$query )
{
  $segments = array();
  if(isset($query['view']))
  {
    $segments[] = $query['view'];
    unset( $query['view'] );
  }
  return $segments;
}
function PvcCalcProParseRoute( $segments )
{
  $vars = array();
  switch($segments[0])
  {
    case 'cart':
    $vars['view'] = 'cart';
    break;
    case 'checkout':
    $vars['view'] = 'checkout';
    break;
    case 'login':
    $vars['view'] = 'login';
    break;
    case 'orders':
    $vars['view'] = 'orders';
    break;
    case 'offers':
    $vars['view'] = 'offers';
    break;
  }
  return $vars;
}
?>
```

I need to enable URL rewriting for **controller** and **task**. For example this line:

```
JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_pvccalcpro&amp;task=helpers');
```

I want to convert to **/component/pvccalcpro/helpers.js**

And this line:

```
JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_pvccalcpro&amp;controller=orders&amp;task=js');
```

I want to convert to **/component/pvccalcpro/orders.js**

I tried to figure out how to accomplish that with official [Joomla Routing Manual](http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component), but after spending so many days it still didn't work out for me. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Here are contents of my **orders** controller for example:

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die();
jimport('joomla.application.component.model');
class PvcCalcProControllerOrders extends PvcCalcProController
{
    function display()
    {
      parent::display();
    }

    function js()
    {
      $t=time()+31536000;
      $expires = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T',$t);
      header('Content-type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8');
      header('Vary: Accept-Encoding');
      header('Last-Modified: Tue, 27 Dec 2001 07:05:43 GMT');
      header('Expires: '.$expires);
      header('Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000');
      require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'assets/js/orders.js');
      die();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your two `JRoute` examples you're passing a path to your component but expecting it to return a path to your Javascript files.

JRoute is for creating human readable URLs for Joomla! components you are trying to use it for Javascript files by the looks of things.

To quote the [Joomla! Doc's page](http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component) - "Joomla can, initially, only create human readable URLs for built-in components."

Comment: I've added contents of **orders** controller for a better picture on how I'm using **js** files. I'm using this method for multilingual ability.